# Unitialized local variable and help correcting

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, dynamic

I am learning about pointers and the `new` operator in class.

In my readArray function I am to read in a size. Use the size to **dynamically** create an integer array. Then assign the array to a pointer, fill it, and return the size and array.

I believe I've gotten that part corrected and fixed but when I try to sort the array, i get the error *"uninitialized local variable `temp` used."*

The problem is though I get that error when I am trying to intialize it.
Any help appreciated thank you. Seeing my errors is very helpful for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* readArray(int&);
void sortArray(int *, const int * );

int main ()
{
    int size = 0;
    int *arrPTR = readArray(size);
    const int *sizePTR = &size;
    sortArray(arrPTR, sizePTR);

    cout<<arrPTR[1]<<arrPTR[2]<<arrPTR[3]<<arrPTR[4];

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}


int* readArray(int &size)
{
    cout<<"Enter a number for size of array.\n";
    cin>>size;
    int *arrPTR = new int[size];

    for(int count = 0; count < (size-1); count++)
    {   
         cout<<"Enter positive numbers to completely fill the array.\n";
         cin>>*(arrPTR+count);
    }

    return arrPTR;
}

void sortArray(int *arrPTR, const int *sizePTR)
{
    int *temp;
    bool *swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0; count < (*sizePTR - 1); count++)
        {
            if(arrPTR[count] > arrPTR[count+1])
            {
                *temp = arrPTR[count];
                arrPTR[count] = arrPTR[count+1];
                arrPTR[count+1] = *temp;
                *swap = true;
            }
        }
    }while (swap);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `temp` as a pointer. You need to allocate it on the heap before dereferencing and assigning to it later. However perhaps a variable on the stack would be preferable?

FYI: You should be aware of the memory leak in `readArray` as well which is leaving callers responsible for calling `delete []`

**Edit:** I hope this will help clear up some of the other problems.

```
#include <iostream>

int* readArray(int&);
void sortArray(int*, int);

int main ()
{
    int size(0); // use stack when possible
    int *arrPTR = readArray(size);
    sortArray(arrPTR, size);

    // arrays are zero based index so loop from 0 to size
    for (int index(0); index < size; ++index)
        std::cout << arrPTR[index];

    delete [] arrPTR; // remember to delete array or we have a memory leak!
    // note: because we did new[] for an array we match it with delete[]
    //       if we just did new we would match it with delete

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int* readArray(int& size)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number for size of array.\n";
    std::cin >> size;
    int *arrPTR = new int[size]; // all news must be deleted!

    // prefer pre-increment to post-increment where you can
    for(int count(0); count < size; ++count)
    {   
         std::cout << "Enter positive numbers to completely fill the array.\n";
         std::cin >> arrPTR[count];
    }

    return arrPTR;
}

// passing size by value is fine (it may be smaller than pointer on some architectures)
void sortArray(int *arrPTR, int size)
{
    // you may want to check if size >= 2 for sanity

    // we do the two loops to avoid going out of bounds of array on last iteration
    for(int i(0); i < size-1; ++i) // the first to compare (all except last)
    {
        for(int j(i+1); j < size; ++j) // the second to compare (all except first)
        {
            // do comparison
            if (arrPTR[i] > arrPTR[j]) // from smallest to biggest (use < to go from biggest to smallest)
            {
                // swap if needed
                int temp(arrPTR[i]); // put this on stack
                arrPTR[i] = arrPTR[j];
                arrPTR[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The OP stated that `temp` must be a pointer?  It's an `int` in this code, not a pointer.

Comment: It doesn't say `temp` must be a pointer in the question but by the newer comments on your answer I now see that perhaps some "interesting requirements" were given and you've covered it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You make temp an int pointer (uninitiialized), and then set the thing it points at (anything/nothing) to arrPTR[ccount].  Since you are using temp only to swap, it should be the same type as those being swapped, in this case: an int.

If it *absolutely* must be a pointer (there is *no* good reason for this, it's slow, confusing, adds potential for errors, and adds potential for memory leaks):

```
int *temp = new int; //make an int for the pointer to point at
bool *swap = new bool; //make an bool for the pointer to point at
do
{
    //your code
}while (swap);
delete temp;
delete swap;
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do but for some reason the instructor said to set them to pointers. My face is the same as your avatar.

Comment: I dont think your instructor was referring to the temp variable specificially.  It can be done, but you shouldnt do that, thats just silly.

Comment: temp and bool is exactly what he is referring to. I guess it's to make it harder :]

Comment: @sircrisp: added description for how to make `temp` and `swap` into working pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a "pointer to int, which you're *not* initializing. When you say `*temp = ...` you're actually assigning to whatever `temp` happens to be pointing, but since you haven't told it what to point to, it can write pretty much anywhere in the address space of your program.

Because of the way you're using them, it seems that `temp` and `swap` shouldn't be pointers at all, just a plain `int` and `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the temp pointer do when you dereference it you are writing to a random part of memory.  Temp doesn't need to be a pointer, it can just be an int.  Just replace EVERY instance of *temp with temp.